Oracle APEX workflow - getting db service name
In my Apex workflows, I'm calling an API which uses sys_context('USERENV', 'SERVICE_NAME'). I dynamically assign it to a variable, which I then use to create a POST request. I need to know my environment (dev, test, etc.). In the API called from workflows, sys_context('USERENV', 'SERVICE_NAME') returns NULL.
Does anyone know why sys_context('USERENV', 'SERVICE_NAME') returns NULL in this scenario or how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!
